# Do we say "A movie of Tarantino's" or "A movie of Tarantino"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, usage, spoken-english

What do i say when i want to mean the same as i would mean by saying "The movie of his"?

"Big bat of his", "Good looking face of hers" etc...
Should i say "Big bat of the guy's" and "Good looking face of girl's"... or without 's's?

You get what i mean.

And also, i somewhy assume there's official (Queen's, literature) english's version of it and there's unofficial, some slang and stuff. If native speakers like to break the rules of this thing, tell me so.

Comment: Would you please capitalize the first person pronouns and names of languages? Thank you.

Comment: It's much more natural to say, "A movie **by** Tarantino."

Comment: Also, one has to know if one is asking about possessives in general or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A movie of Tarantino's would be understood as a movie that he has produced or directed.

A movie of Tarantino would be understood as a movie about him.

**His** and **hers** do not take the apostrophe **s**. They are already possessive pronouns.

Neither is an apostrophe required with **the pretty face of the girl** or **the pretty faces of (the) girls** as the preposition **of** indicates the possessive here.

But **the girl's pretty face** would be singular and **the girls' pretty faces** would be plural.

As to the slang, I must leave it to others to assist you.

Comment: I meant "girl's" and "guy's" that can take the apostrophe s

Comment: Anyway.. Why is it so that you can say "of tarantino's" but you can't say "of the girl's"? I don't really feel the difference. Both of them would mean "of his " and "of hers"

Comment: Apostrophe S after girl would indicate a single girl (girl's) Placing the apostrophe after the plural S (girls') would indicate more than one girl. Thus **the girl's toys** means one girl. **The girls' toys** means more than one girl.

Comment: The apostrophe serves to indicate a subtle difference. For example, to say **a picture of the girl** means a picture showing the girl. To say **a picture of the girl's** means a picture belonging to the girl. The same is true in the plural.

Comment: Your answer is only about possessives. The question seemed broader than that.

Answer (score 1):

In slangy English, one sometimes says:

"That big smile of his gets on my nerves", compare that to: His big smile gets on my nerves."

The form consisting of "That x of [personal pronoun] is a spoken form that can be used to denigrate or praise.

"That pretty face of hers is always popping up in my mind."

As for movies made by Tarantino, usually, we would say: "Tarentino's movie [name of movie] is one of his worst. Or: "That Tarantino movie [name of movie] is" etc.  No "a".

Using the other form, one might say: That movie of Tarantino's that takes place in the desert is not too bad."

Generally speaking, I would not say "a movie of Tarantino" when I mean: "One of Tarantino's movies", but one, of course, could say it: A movie of Tarantino I particularly dislike is Kill Bill Vol. IV.

Just saying "a movie of his" only works if the conversation has already established whose movies are being discussed. "One of his I really like is Kill Bill Vol. 1". One of his means a movie he directed.

A movie of Tarantino's or a movie of [by] Tarantino both work in speech.

For me, of here does not mean about necessarily. A movie of love [yes, there it's about love.]